# Error al mostrar cronometro en label vb

Tags: vb.net, vba, vb

he escrito un par de funciones para medir el tiempo desde que presiono un botón, quiero que el tiempo en segundos aparezca en la label pero solo imprime un cero, no sé que es lo que estoy haciendo mal, espero alguien pueda ayudarme, este es mi código hasta el momento

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Inicio_E As Integer = 0
    Public Tiempo_E As Integer = 0
    Function Iniciar_E()
        Inicio_E = Environment.TickCount
        Return Inicio_E
    End Function

    Public Tiempo_Entrenamiento = 0
    Function Transcurriendo_E()
        Tiempo_Entrenamiento = Environment.TickCount
        Return ((Tiempo_Entrenamiento - Iniciar_E())) / 1000
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Iniciar_E()
        Label1.Text = Transcurriendo_E()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: El tiempo que tratas de imprimir, en ticks, es nulo... la diferencia de ticks es nada, y por eso imprime cero. estas llamando a Enviroment.TickCount casi al mismo tiempo las dos veces...

Comment: @gbianchi Qué me recomiendas hacer? Me extraña porque antes ya lo había intentado de esa forma y si funcionaba

Comment: La funcion no debia ser como esta... aca en lo que mostras la diferencia es nula.

Comment: Si las funciones no están bien declaradas, puede que el problema sea que las funciones no devuelven parámetro alguno, también puede ser que al coger la propiedad Tickcount se coja el mismo parámetro y resulte en 0...
A parte en la rutina del botón hay una asignación mal hecha...

Answer (score 0):

Si pones el Inicio_E en la misma rutina que el Tiempo_E lo que pasa es que no pasan ni segundos al estar en la misma rutina y por eso te sale el 0.

Si lo haces de este modo que te muestro a continuación, veras que cada vez que pulses el boton1 habrá transcurrido más de un segundo, ya que el primer reloj lo inicias en el evento Load del formulario.

Con la función DateDiff puedes configurar si quieres ver segundos, minutos, horas, etc...

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Inicio_E As Date = Now
    Public Tiempo_E As Date = Now

    Public Sub Iniciar_E()
        Inicio_E = Date.Now
    End Sub

    Public Function Transcurriendo_E() As String
        Tiempo_E = Date.Now
        Return DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Inicio_E, Tiempo_E).ToString
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Label1.Text = Transcurriendo_E() ' y este el Fin y Devuelve la Resta
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Iniciar_E() ' Esto es el Inicio de la Cuenta
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Esto es el mismo codigo escrito de otra manera.. :(

Comment: No es lo Mismo, No se Divide

Comment: aja.. y esto soluciona el problema que no sabemos cual es exactamtente porque??? por favor, que tu respuesta sea completa para que no tengamos que hacer todas esas preguntass ;)

Comment: Aún No Estaba Corregido del Todo. Saludos.

Comment: Pero esto es solo codigo, no explica el problema ni la solucion.. a eso me refiero...

Comment: Ahora esta bien comentado y supongo que esto es lo que pide el usuario...